# How to get each voxel's density of Volume object from Python code

Tags: python, scripting, volumetrics

First of all, my purpose is exporting/generating raw volume data from triangle mesh. Latest blender (2.93) has "Mesh To Volume" modifier so I tried it.

When I created Volume with "Mesh To Volume" modifier, it seems that successfully generated volumes, but its Volume.grids property always empty so I can't access density data.

Here is my code:

```
volume_object = C.active_object
volume = volume_object.data
len(volume.grids) # <- always be 0
```

Is there any method for getting density values of Volume object?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I presume that in order to access the data generated by the modifier you will have to use the "evaluated" object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).